# Can't query a record in MongoDB when using "$" selector

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a weird problem when using NodeJS with Mongoose when querying a record in MongoDB.
I have a Product model file is like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  brand: String,
  shorDescription: String,
  description: String,
  price: Number,
  salePercent: Number,
  rating: Number,
  color: String,
  size: [String],
});

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

And in the controller file, my code is like this:

```
const Product = require("../models/product.model");

exports.getProducts = async (req, res) => {
  const products = await Product.find({ rating: { $lte: "5" } });

  console.log(`products: ${products}`);

  res.json({
    products: products,
  });
};
```

`Product.find({})` works perfectly -> returns all the records in the product collection

`Product.find({brand: "Nike"})` still works fine -> returns all the "Nike" products.

the weird thing is when I use $ selector in `Product.find({ rating: { $lte: "5" } })`, I receive nothing while I have several products which are match the condition in the product collection.

Someone help me :(((

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB query operators are type sensitive.  The problem here is that the query expression is a string ("5"), but the data is a number (e.g. 5).  Since the types are incomparable, they will never match the `$lte` expression.

For instance, the query for `{rating: {$lte: "5"}}` will match documents like:

```json
{rating: "5"}
{rating: "4.5"}
{rating: "25"}
{rating: ""}
```

but not like:

```json
{rating: 5}
{rating: 4.5}
```

Comment: Specifically, the OP is querying `{ $lte: "5" }`, which will match any documents with a _string_ value that's lexicographically less than "5" — in this case, "5" itself, and any string value that starts with a lower Unicode codepoint than 52.  So it'll match "4", "23", "+99", "3ABC", and so forth.  It will not match documents with a _number_ value, which according to your schema, is what all your documents will have.  This will be fixed by changing it to `{ $lte: 5 }`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I demonstrated backward, I'll edit that.

Comment: Ohhh I got it, thank you very much guys, the only weird thing here is me when trying to compare string with number :))))))

Comment: @Hindie You got it